# cloudsim install problem

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hello
i tried to install clousim. i installed all of the necessary things. but it give me this error.

:/home/ossl2/Documents# ./cloudsim-1.4.0/bin/create_cloudsim.py ****@gmail.com ****** ***** us-east-1a
ERROR:boto:401 Unauthorized
ERROR:boto:
`OptInRequired`You are not subscribed to this service. Please go to http://aws.amazon.com to subscribe.

3408e248-67eb-444f-810c-c4a3b412f256
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./cloudsim-1.4.0/bin/create_cloudsim.py", line 50, in 
machine = cloudsim.cloudsim_bootstrap(username, tmp_fname.name, auto_launch_constellation)

File "/home/ossl2/Documents/cloudsim-1.4.0/cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 376, in cloudsim_bootstrap
constellation_directory, website_distribution)

File "/home/ossl2/Documents/cloudsim-1.4.0/cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 124, in launch
sim_security_group= ec2conn.create_security_group(sim_sg_name, "simulator security group for constellation %s" % constellation_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 2286, in create_security_group
SecurityGroup, verb='POST')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1069, in get_object
raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized

`OptInRequired`You are not subscribed to this service. Please go to http://aws.amazon.com to subscribe.3408e248-67eb-444f-810c-c4a3b412f256

what the problem is?
ps: in here i put * instead of key and secret key .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2683/cloudsim-install-problem/) by [robi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/338/robi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Robi,

it seems a credential problem. Do you have an AWS account? Make sure that you are specifying your public and secret key when you run the create_cloudsim.py tool.

Ex: ./create_cloudsim.py cloudsim@gmail.com RKIAIFWTGCDUX7NZ2BSA aRYYgTc36NFZ31KX+E3Jh40qtgS/qXsFrdW51X9G us-east-1a

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0